# Is there any difference between $("#item1 #item2") and $("#item1>#item2")?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I was reviewing code and found that

```
$("#item1 #item2") and $("#item1>#item2")
```

are used interchangeably. Is there any difference or is it one and the same?

Comment: What does the html look like for that code? Are the multiple `#item1`s? If there are, then it's invalid.

Comment: You might want to read about [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors). In the first selector you have a descendant combinator, and in the second selector you have a child combinator.

Comment: @Eric- Those items are unique...I should have just given the example using classes instead of ids...anyways point taken.

Comment: @Sime- Thanks for the info....now it is pretty clear to me with the help of examples from Eric and others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both will match

```
<div id="item1">
    <div id="item2">
    </div>
</div>
```

But only the first one will match

```
<div id="item1">
    <div>
        <div id="item2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first expression uses the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/). The `>` symbol in the second expression is the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/). Both are standard CSS selectors.

However, since `id`s **must** be unique, both are overcomplicated. Instead, you should just use `$('#item2')`

Comment: Good point about not using multiple IDs in a selector - totally pointless.

Comment: @Orbling: Unless of course, you sometimes don't want a match, if you execute the same jQuery on every page.

Comment: @Orbling, I disagree. If your writing in a .js file which will apply to more than one page, if one page has #page1 #item and another has #page2 #item, you need both id's if you only want to target one page. So there is a point to multiple ID selectors.

Comment: have seem too many duplicated IDs. Good point to mention IDs *must* be unique.

Comment: @Jeremy B.: If there is an `#item` on the page, it will still be the only element of that name.  So in essence you are using the `#page1` as a check - I would say that is a case of poor identifier choice; when they can appear in multiple uses across the domain of the codebase.

Comment: @Orbling, I'm guessing you have never used a js file, and have all your javascript on the page. Or have always had complete control of markup. There are times when an ID will exist on separate pages, making it still unique, but you want to only address it on a specific page. In this case you need multiple ID's in the selector or your javascript will bleed over.

Comment: @Jeremy B.: I understand the situation quite well thank you.  Yes, always have full control of mark up.  At least with regard to identifier choice, HTML/CSS builders take instruction from coders on such things as a rule.

Answer (score 1):

The same as the CSS selectors

```
#this #that
```

means any `#that` that is a child of `#this`.

Where as

```
#this>#that
```

Means only `#that` which is a direct descendant of `#this`.

[More reading on descendant selectors.](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200510/css_21_selectors_part_2/)

Answer (score 0):

The `>` sign means "include only elements that are direct children of that element". So if you want to select only the children being subnodes of `#item1`, use it, otherwise use first option.

Answer (score 0):

`>` means the *immediate*, direct child.

**Direct**

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Indirect**

```
<div id="a">
    <div>
        <div id="b">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/